# Yii in-place crud text widget

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, crud

I'm using Yii framework to build myself a poor man's project tracking system. The goal is to have a in place "crud" widget/form that is similar to [basecamp's](https://basecamp.com/) note widget to display note(s) with a title and a content field. (I no longer use basecamp therefore cannot post the image of what their note widget looks like :-( )

Using Yii, I have a client model and I would like to display in a div all the notes corresponding to this client and have CRUD functionality for these notes right in the same `webroot/client/view/client_id` page.

The closest implementation I found online is done purely in jquery, [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), but lacks of create and delete functionality. Also, it has no Yii model (CActiveRecord) support, meaning one needs to hard-wire the data transmitted back and forth in controller code without taking advantage of Yii's MVC setup.

What I have now: A hidden form that's submitted via AJAX (forcCreation) and an Zii CListView widget (for Retrieve) of the note(s), which takes advantage of the built-in zii widget update functionality `$.fn.yiiListView.update('clistview_id');`, but I am rather stuck on the U and D part of the game using Yii/Zii widget, jquery, or a combination of those.

My client/view.php snippet:

```
<div class="note_create">
    <?php echo CHtml::button('Add new note',array('class'=>'create-note-button')) ?>
    <div class="create-note-form" style="display: none;">
    <!-- _createNote is just a CActiveForm with a CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton-->
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_createNote', array('client' => $model, 'note' => $note)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="note_browser">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'id' => 'clist_note_browser',
        'dataProvider' => $model->noteSearch(),
        'itemView' => '_note', // refers to the partial view named '_note'
        'emptyText' => 'No notes found.',
        'sortableAttributes' => array(
            'note.title',
            'note.last_modify'
        ),
        ));
    ?>
</div>
```

A very simple Note Model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "note".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'note':
 * @property string $nid
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $content
 * @property string $first_create
 * @property string $last_modify
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property ClientNote $client  ClientNote an intermediate table with two columns: nid, cid
 */
class Note extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function relations()
    {   
        return array('client' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ClientNote', 'nid'),);
    }
    ...
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Yii's Gii module has this kind of widget (for editing table prefix in model generation and other stuff). Take a look at its code. But I think only UPDATE is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start check out this, it helps you to understand how do you want:

http://help.discretelogix.com/php/yii/enable-in-place-editing-in-yii-grid.htm

after you understood, you need to create your own widget that does this

you can check out existing extensions that tries to do what you are after:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/editablegridview/

http://yiitutorials.net/easy/creating-a-widget-with-the-yii-framework

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/escrollablegridview/

You need to study all these, and understand how they work, so you should be able to take one and extend to fit your needs. Good luck.

Comment: Great. I'll study all these and, hopefully report back how they work out together soon! thank you.

Comment: Humm, I wonder if there is already a widget that is doing what I am after...even a Zend one is fine. Can't afford to spend time customizing Cgridview for a in-place crud widget as the project time constraint (also Cgridview may not be best widget for displaying notes, IMO). For now, I'd go for in-place CRD and update the note in its own page. I plan to implement the D part with a simple ajaxbutton in the itemview in CListView.

Comment: was able to address the update task using jeditable from [link](http://help.discretelogix.com/php/yii/enable-in-place-editing-in-yii-grid.htm) @pentium10 provided above. Delete task is easier than I expected, by adding a `CHtml::ajaxLink` to item view (used by CListView) with proper data (note id) and a success callback that invoke `$.fn.yiiListView.update('clistview_id')` to refresh the CListView widget